# PHP expression resources consumption

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following:

```
$fileMetadata[$key][0] ="";
$fileMetadata[$key][1] = $message->getSubject();
$fileMetadata[$key][2] = //Expresion
...
$fileMetadata[$key][0] =Expresion;
```

I need the array to be ordered with the indexes 0,1,2,... that is why the first thing I do is to assign "" to array in cero. I could also do something like this:

```
$fileMetadata[$key][1] = $message->getSubject();
$fileMetadata[$key][2] = //Expresion
...
$fileMetadata[$key][0] =Expresion
$fileMetadata[$key] = array_values($fileMetadata[$key]);
```

I have not tested the second, I am pretty sure that the fist implementation consumes much less resources, but I am not 100% sure. Can anyone confirm?
Aside from this. Where I can find the algorithms of the PHP functions implementation?

Comment: why did you not test it yourself? second question: do web search for "PHP source code", maybe.

Comment: Your first point is 100% right. I did the search an found the Github page, but it's difficult to find anything there. I thought there was something like an indexed help or something like that. Thank anyways for the time of reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your first approach is more efficient since you will take `O(n*2)` in the second approach and ultimately consume twice the memory since you're copying the array over into a new array.

The implementation of `array_values` can be found in the [php source code here](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_TRUNK/ext/standard/array.c#2968) in `ext/standard/array.c` starting on line 2968.

The implementation is non-destructive, meaning it will create a new array of values based on the given argument array, discarding the keys. The equivalent implementation of this function in PHP would look something like this...

```
function array_values(Array $array) {
    $newArray = [];
    foreach($array as $value) {
        $newArray[] = $value;
    }
    return $newArray;
}
```

Though what you might notice from this implementation is that it doesn't necesarily change the order of your elements in the array at all. It merely recreates the array using number keys starting from 0.

So, for example, in your array...

```
$array = [
    1 => 'foo',
    2 => 'bar',
    0 => 'baz'
];
```

`array_values($array)` would give you...

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "foo"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "bar"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "baz"
}
```

Notice that `baz` still comes last even though the key is now `2` instead of `0`. This may not necessarily be what you want if I understand your requirements correctly.

I would stick with your first approach instead.